# Get a shortened script of more scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

On category pages of my shop I have the list of my product and I need to change the position of a wishlist button of every product on the list, so I create these jQuery scripts:

```
jQuery('.product:nth-child(1) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(1) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(2) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(2) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(3) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(3) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(4) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(4) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(5) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(5) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(6) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(6) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(7) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(7) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(8) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(8) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(9) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(9) .wishlist');
jQuery('.product:nth-child(10) .btn').insertBefore('.product:nth-child(10) .wishlist');
and so on...
```

I want shorten my scripts in only one script or function, without use lot of :nth-child(x).

How can I do this?

P:S. I cannot use the script

```
jQuery('.product .btn').insertBefore('.product .wishlist');
```

because every .btn elements go in every .product elements.

Comment: Post the related HTML markup also. Also, please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, you don't need to post 100+ `product` divs. Just post two with `.btn` and `.wishlist` so that others can understand the markup. Also, mention how the markup should look like after using `insertBefore`.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to have shorten version of my scripts in only one script or function, without use lot of :nth-child(x)?